# Conflicting compile time behaviour using as keyword against generic types in C#

Tags: c#, generics

When attempting to use the C# "as" keyword against a non-generic type that cannot be cast to, the compiler gives an error that the type cannot be converted.

However when using the "as" keyword against a generic type the compiler gives no error:

```
public class Foo { }

public class Bar<T> { }

public class Usage<T> {
   public void Test() {
      EventArgs args = new EventArgs();
      var foo = args as Foo;     // Compiler Error: cannot convert type
      var bar = args as Bar<T>;  // No compiler error
   }
}
```

I discovered this behaviour in a much larger code base where the lack of a compile time error led to an issue at runtime.

Is the conflicting behaviour by design? If so, does anyone have any insight as to why?

Comment: FYI: R# does flag it with the warning "Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution that is inherited from both 'EventArgs' and 'Bar<T>'"

Comment: @juharr thanks! I guess it goes to show that the issue is detectable in C#. I also double checked the issue against the F# compiler which like R# picks up the invalid cast (but in the case of F# it is marked as an error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `§7.10.11 The as operator` C# 5.0 Specification says:

> In an operation of the form E as T, E must be an expression and T must be a reference type, a type parameter known to be a reference type, or a nullable type. Furthermore, at least one of the following must be true, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - An identity (§6.1.1), implicit nullable (§6.1.4), implicit reference (§6.1.6), boxing (§6.1.7), explicit nullable (§6.2.3), explicit
>     reference (§6.2.4), or unboxing (§6.2.5) conversion exists from E to
>     T.
> - **The type of E or T is an open type.**
> - E is the null literal.

So `args as Foo` gives an error because none of this is true. But in the second case, `Bar<T>` is an open type, and the spec explains open type as, `§4.4.2 Open and closed types` :

> An open type is a type that involves **type parameters**. More specifically:
>
> - **A type parameter defines an open type**.  [...]

Comment: I just found it in spec, but not sure what makes an open type special in this case.

Comment: thanks! This answers the question "is the conflicting behaviour by design" with a yes. And the insight into why seems to be the naive implementation of the translation of the expression you mention from the documentation.

Comment: but I should note that I'm not 100% sure that it's true. that's the only logical explanation I can think of.

Comment: From what you've said I don't think it is translated as `args is Bar<T> ? (Bar<T>)(object)args : (Bar<T>)null; ` since that would require `args` to be of type `dynamic` which it isn't. I've not got the spec (no office installed) so I'm only interpreting second hand.

Answer (score -3):

"Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Comment: this does not explain why `args as Bar<T>`  does not give any compiler error.