# How is "as" operator translated when the right-side operand is generic?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, casting, as-operator

I have just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150199/3010968) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28149927/3010968) but I'm not entirely convinced of my answer.There are two things I'm wondering, consider this code:

```
class Foo<T>
{ 
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        string str = "foo";
        Foo<T> f = str as Foo<T>;
    }
}
```

According to `C# Specification 5.0`, there are two different kinds of conversion of `as operator`.

> If the compile-time type of `E` is not `dynamic`, the operation `E as T` produces the same result as
>
> ```
> E is T ? (T)(E) : (T)null
> ```
>
> If the compile-time type of `E` is `dynamic`, unlike the cast operator the `as operator` is not dynamically bound (§7.2.2). Therefore the expansion in this case is:
>
> ```
> E is T ? (T)(object)(E) : (T)null
> ```

Since, this is invalid because of `(Foo<T>)str`

```
str is Foo<T> ? (Foo<T>)str : (Foo<T>)null;
```

I thought it should be translated as:

```
str is Foo<T> ? (Foo<T>)(object)str : (Foo<T>)null;
```

But the spec says this only happens when the type of `E` is `dynamic`.

So my questions are:

1. Is the compiler translating this expression to a code that is normally invalid?
2. When the type of `E` is dynamic why first it casts `E` to `object` then `T` while the `(T)E` is completely valid?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on compiler operation but in the case of nothing being dynamic the compiler knows if `E is T` and thus probably doesn't actually emit the code given but does whichever part is appropriate. In the case of it being dynamic I would assume it is something to do with forcing it to be boxed for some reason but I don't know enough about the behaviour of dynamic expressions to do any more than guess...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is the compiler translating this expression to a code that is normally
>   invalid?

After staring at the spec for about an hour, I'm starting to convince myself that this is simply an edge-case which was *overlooked* in the specification. Note that this is merely a way for the C# language composers to express the `as` operator with the semantics of the `is` operator.

The compiler *doesn't actually* convert the `as` operator to a ternary operator with an `is`. It will emit an IL call to `isinst`, both for `as` and `is`:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldstr "foo"
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: isinst class ConsoleApplication2.Foo`1<!T>
IL_000d: stloc.1
IL_000e: ret
```

Looking at the compiled DLL, the `as` operator remains untouched.

> When the type of E is dynamic why first it casts E to object then T
>   while the (T)E is completely valid?

This is described in the fine-print of the specification:

> If the compile-time type of E is dynamic, **unlike the cast operator
>   the as operator is not dynamically bound** (§7.2.2). Therefore the
>   expansion in this case is:

```
E is T ? (T)(object)(E) : (T)null
```

The cast to `object` is needed to make the use of `as` possible with `dynamic` objects. `as` is a *compile-time* operation while `dynamic` objects are bound only at *run-time*.

The compiler actually treats `dynamic` type objects as type `object` to begin with:

```
class Foo<T> 
{
    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        dynamic str = "foo";
        Foo<T> f = str as Foo<T>;
    }
}
```

`str` is actually treated as `object` to begin with:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo`1<T>
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void SomeMethod () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 15 (0xf)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] object,
            [1] class Foo`1<!T>
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldstr "foo"
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: ldloc.0
        IL_0008: isinst class Foo`1<!T>
        IL_000d: stloc.1
        IL_000e: ret
    } // end of method Foo`1::SomeMethod
}
```

### Edit:

After talking to Vladimir Reshetnikov from the Managed Languages Team, he explains what the semantic of the representation from the "as operator" to "cast operator" actually tries to convay:

> I agree, there is some imprecise language in the spec too. It says 'as' operator is always applicable if an open type involved, but then describes its evaluation in terms of casts, that might be not valid in some cases. It *should say* that casts in the expansion **do not represent normal C# cast operator but just represent conversions that are permitted in 'as' operators.** I'll take a note to fix it. Thanks!